# When adding a widget, what kind of widget should I used to add images and text and styling?

Tags: widgets, widget-text

Is there such a thing? I would settle for images, text and maybe headers.

I know I can add HTML into the text widget. So is that what I should be doing? But how do I add images to the site? That widget doesn't have the image upload option.

Thanks!

Comment: You can simply use text widget as it allows HTML.  So you can directly enter your IMG tag within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only out-of-the-box solution is to use the text widget and hand-code your HTML and images.

However, there are plugins, [this is one I use](http://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/).